# Remove tags and content from a (text) file in Java

Tags: java, regex, xml

**What'd be the best way to remove xml tags and content between them from a file in Java?** I think I'd first read the file into a String variable, then use `replaceAll()` and regex to remove the concerned part then write the remainder into another file.

Also, if the part to be removed looks like:

```
<tag id="abc" name="xyz">
  content goes here..
</tag>
```

**Then what would be the best regex pattern to match it?**

Comment: "then use replaceAll()" -> [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747), [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701166). In short, use proper XML parser, avoid regex for this kind of problems at all costs.

Comment: Another mandatory link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Comment: As mentioned above, it's hard to match these tags with regex. The best way I see is to just compare lines to see if they share characteristics of tags like <>, then ignore them. Might not work best, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to remove XML tags from variable `str`:

```
str = str.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "")
```